# Multiple `select` `option`s in datatables dropdown filter instead of unique option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

This issue only happened at column index `6`. Other column have one unique option for all values.

This is the screenshot:
Other column

[image]

Column index `6`

[image]

This is my current dropdown declaration in `initComplete`:
Reference: [here](https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

```
api.columns([2,5,6,7]).every( function (currentValue, index) {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value=""></option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        $(this).val()
                    );

                    column
                        .search( val , true, false )
                        .draw();
                } );
                
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( data, j ) {
                switch (currentValue){
                    // case 2:
                    //     data = data.match(/SK (([a-zA-Z]\w+) *)+/g);
                    //     select.append( '<option value="'+data+'">'+data+'</option>' )
                    //     break;
                    case 6:
                        data = data.match(/<input type="hidden" data-status="[23]">/g);
                        var status = $.parseHTML(data[0])[0].getAttribute('data-status');
                        if (status == '2'){
                            text = 'DONE';
                        }
                        else if (status == '3'){
                            text = 'VERIFIED';
                        }
                        select.append( '<option value="'+status+'">'+text+'</option>' )

                        break;
                    default:
                        select.append( '<option value="'+data+'">'+data+'</option>' )

                }
            } );
        } );
```

Update on `<td>` column HTML data:

```
<td data-status="DONE">
    <form method="GET" action="http://localhost:8000/reports/5" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">
        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="View">
    </form>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://localhost:8000/reports/5/edit">Edit</a>
                                        <form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/reports/5" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="vabNTlGCu40MG4bs62uTs7vQHoQ5K5GJI1SHCUSZ">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Delete</button>
        </form>
                    <label class="badge badge-success">
        DONE
    </label>
</td>
```

Comment: The question does not show us the table data, so this is pure guesswork: You are using `unique()` to remove duplicate column values - but that operates on the _entire_ content of each `<td>` column cell. In `case 6`, you then select one piece of that data. There is no guarantee that the results are still going to be unique. By analogy: If I have `cat`, `bat` and `rat`, those 3 words are unique. But if I select the 2nd letter of each word, I have duplicates: `a`, `a`, and `a`. You can show us your data to avoid the guesswork.

Comment: @andrewJames I've added the html code as requested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I was hoping you would show us the data you are using. One `<td>` cell is not sufficient to see what is happening. Having said that, it really does seem (as best I can tell) that you are doing what I guessed: you appear to be extracting duplicate substrings from unique values. So, if you have the following 2 cells in that column: `<td>foo<label>DELETE</label></td>` and `<td>bar<label>DELETE</label></td>`, then these 2 cells are unique. But then you extract the text `DELETE` from each of them - resulting in a list of duplicate values.

Comment: So, extract that list to an array and then apply `unique().sort()` to that new list. But as before, there is a fair amount of guesswork, here. So please try to clarify the question. See [mre].